# How to have multiple bullets as a placeholder

Tags: html

Title pretty much says it all, I have an input with a placeholder of lots of bullets, So I have to have lots of •. Is there any way I can do something like &bull*5;?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In straight HTML5? No, you can't use a calculation like that. There is a placeholder attribute on the input tag you can use.

You could use JavaScript to do it, but the script world be much heavier than simply hard-coding five bullets.

Setting placeholder text using CSS is inconsistent and really just a hack, so take that option as a no.